# Home/End jumping only a group of characters, not to the begin/end of the line

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, laptop

The <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys on my laptop (reached by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+arrows) jumps only to the next non-alphanumerical character (like ./_) instead of jumping the full line.
I guess this is an optional behavior which is not too bad, but I'd like to switch to the traditional one.

Comment: Has the key opposite to [End] really the label *Begin*?

Comment: It's [Home] actually.

Comment: In which application?

Comment: A.B. -> System-wide.

Comment: After testing on another machine that has dedicated [begin] and [end] keys, it turns out that [ctrl]+arrows has the same behavior.
Hence in both cases the combination is mapped to an action (move to the next nonalpha symbol) that is different from the `begin/end` action.